# Как на android 6+ получить mac адрес WIFI

Tags: android, kotlin

можно ли как-то без танцев с бубном получить mac адрес WIFI. Раньше получал так:

```
val macWifi = (context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager).connectionInfo.macAddress
```

но на более новых версиях отказывается работать. Возвращает  02:00:00:00:00:00

Comment: как бы это не было странно, но попробуйте дать вашему приложению ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission...так же не забудьте что его следует запрашивать в рантайме.

Comment: а в этом есть какая-то связь? попробовал эффекта нет. все так же  02:00:00:00:00:00(

Comment: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-hardware-id